# The fade effects around the edittext edges in android

Tags: android, android-layout, roundedcorners-dropshadow

I need to design the search textbox with the fade effects around the edges.(Please look at the picture by link: [The fade effect around the edges](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7458/12734572245_303c28bd7a_o.png)).

Anybody can give me an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: are you asking it in an artist's perspective or a programmer's perspective?

Comment: programmer's perspective. I need to know how to design this search edittext by XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can to it by simply create a Class lets say YourCustomEditText and extending the default EditText class.
You can to it like this:

```
public class YourCustomEditText extends EditText
```

- Then override the OnDraw method, only call the super(canvas) at the end so it wont draw as the default look.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
     canvas.save();
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();
  }
  ```
- instantiate it in the activity

  YourCustomEditText yourCustomEditText;
- then on the onCreate of the activity, you can cast it as an YourCustomEditText even with same EditText tag

  yourCustomEditText = (YourCustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.customEditText);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to know how to make a fade effects around the edges. Please see this picture: https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7458/12734572245_303c28bd7a_o.png